# How to convert text to speech in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a scenario where I need to convert text into speech. Is there any way to do this using Selenium with Java?

Comment: No, there isn't

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Selenium can launch speechinput triggers, but the actual speaking itself can't be done by Selenium. I'd advise to get a third party TTS tool to use live or as a sample in combination with Selenium.